# Batch File Math (Subtraction) Stopped Working

Tags: batch-file, math, cmd, subtraction

I know that there must be some syntax issue on my end with this, but I can't for the life of me figure this out right now. This is a script I put together a few months back to automatically download some files for me as they release every month. It was working fine, however this month I noticed that nothing was downloading. After some troubleshooting and investigation, I found that the month variable was setting itself to "-1" instead of subtracting "1" from it's current value. As a result of this I'm unable to get the proper file name to attempt the download. It's the same match that I'm using on days, revision number, and year number, but for some reason the month variable just isn't cooperating with me and I can't figure out why.

```
    :MASTER
        @echo off
        mode con:cols=100 lines=5
    ::Setup First Download
        for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ExampleRegistryKey" /v ExampleString 2^>nul') do set "ExampleDir=%%~b"
        pushd "%ExampleDir%"
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr SQLiteHome Example.ini') do set SQLiteHome=%%a
        ::Revision Number
        set num=17
        set /a "num=num-1"
        ::Begin set date
        for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
        goto :end_set_date
        :set_date
        if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
        goto :eof
        :end_set_date
        set dd=31
```

This section here is where the month starts to equal -1 instead of current one subtracted from the current month.

```
        set /a "mm=mm-1"
        if %mm%==9 set mm=09
        if %mm%==8 set mm=08
        if %mm%==7 set mm=07
        if %mm%==6 set mm=06
        if %mm%==5 set mm=05
        if %mm%==4 set mm=04
        if %mm%==3 set mm=03
        if %mm%==2 set mm=02
        if %mm%==1 set mm=01
        if %mm%==0 set /a "yy=yy-1"
        if %mm%==0 set mm=12
        Set EarlyEntry=early_up_sqlite_r
        Set FullEntry=update_sqlite_r
        Set MstarEntry=mstar_ext_sqlite_r
        Set PSNEntry=psn_ext_sqlite_r
        set CurrentEntry=%EarlyEntry%
        set ThisFile=%CurrentEntry%%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%.exe
        ECHO %ThisFile%
        set INIentry=EarlyLast
    ::Create %WorkingDirectory%\Dates.txt and Downloads.ini
        set INIfile=C:\ProgramData\SA_Updater\Downloads.ini
        set WorkingDirectory=C:\ProgramData\SA_Updater\
        set OldDownloads=C:\ProgramData\SA_Updater\Downloads\
        set PSNini=PSNLast
        set MSTARini=MSTARLast
        set Fullini=FullLast
        set Earlyini=EarlyLast
        echo %PSNini%
        echo Dates > %WorkingDirectory%\Dates.txt
        if not exist "%WorkingDirectory%" mkdir "%WorkingDirectory%"
        if not exist "%OldDownloads%" mkdir "%OldDownloads%"
        pusd %WorkingDirectory%
        if not exist "%INIfile%" (
        ECHO %PSNini%= > %INIfile%
        ECHO %MSTARini%= >> %INIfile%
        ECHO %Fullini%= >> %INIfile%
        ECHO %Earlyini%= >> %INIfile%
        )
    :ObtainVariables
        ::Find the Last version downloaded
```

This is where I've kept a log for the download attempts
                echo Dates > %WorkingDirectory%\Dates.txt
The output is looking like this:

```
Dates 

http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r16_2018-131.exe 
http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r15_2018-131.exe 
http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r14_2018-131.exe
```

Instead of:

```
Dates 

http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r16_20180731.exe 
http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r15_20180731.exe 
http://Example.com/updates/early_up_sqlite_r14_20180731.exe
```

The rest of the script:

```
            for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr %INIentry% %INIfile%') do set LastINIfile=%%a
            ECHO %LastINIfile%
        ::Revision Number
            set num=17
            set /a "num=num-1"
        ::Begin set date
            for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
            goto :end_set_date
            :set_date
            if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
            for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
            goto :eof
            :end_set_date
            set dd=31
            set /a "mm=mm-1"
            if %mm%==9 set mm=09
            if %mm%==8 set mm=08
            if %mm%==7 set mm=07
            if %mm%==6 set mm=06
            if %mm%==5 set mm=05
            if %mm%==4 set mm=04
            if %mm%==3 set mm=03
            if %mm%==2 set mm=02
            if %mm%==1 set mm=01
            if %mm%==0 set /a "yy=yy-1"
            if %mm%==0 set mm=12
            set ThisFile=%CurrentEntry%%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%.exe
            goto Download
    :Download
        ::Setup Download Variables
            cls
            set Download=http://Example.com/updates/%ThisFile%
            GOTO TryDownload
    :TryDownload
        ::Add Download Attempt to %WorkingDirectory%\Dates.txt
            echo %Download% >> %WorkingDirectory%\Dates.txt
        ::Is the file download? If so, start the install
            cls
            mode con:cols=100 lines=10
            powershell "Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer '%Download%' '%DownloadDir%'"
            mode con:cols=100 lines=5
            cls
            ::ping localhost -n 3 >nul
            if exist C:\ProgramData\SA_Updater\%ThisFile% (
            GOTO StartInstall
            ) else (
        ::Try Downloading
            GOTO TryAgain
            )
            cls
    :TryAgain
        set /a "num=num-1"
        if %mm%==9 set mm=09
        if %mm%==8 set mm=08
        if %mm%==7 set mm=07
        if %mm%==6 set mm=06
        if %mm%==5 set mm=05
        if %mm%==4 set mm=04
        if %mm%==3 set mm=03
        if %mm%==2 set mm=02
        if %mm%==1 set mm=01
        if %num%==0 set /a "dd=dd-1"
        if %dd%==27 set /a "mm=mm-1"
        if %mm%==0 set /a "yy=yy-1"
        if %mm%==0 set mm=12
        if %dd%==27 set dd=33
        if %num%==0 set num=17
        set ThisFile=%CurrentEntry%%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%.exe
        set Download=http://Example.com/updates/%ThisFile%
        set DownloadDir=%WorkingDirectory%%ThisFile%
        if %ThisFile% EQU %LastINIfile% GOTO CheckEarly
        GOTO TryDownload
        )
    :StartInstall
        %WorkingDirectory%%ThisFile% /w /v"INSTALLPREREQUISITES=0"
        robocopy %WorkingDirectory% %OldDownloads% %ThisFile%
        pushd %WorkingDirectory%
        del %ThisFile%
        del /Q /A H *.tmp
        GOTO DoINIstuff
    ::Update ThisFile
        :CheckEarly
            if %CurrentEntry% EQU %EarlyEntry% GOTO SetupFull
            GOTO CheckFull
        :CheckFull
            if %CurrentEntry% EQU %FullEntry% GOTO SetupMstar
            GOTO CheckMstar
        :CheckMstar
            if %CurrentEntry% EQU %MstarEntry% GOTO SetupPSN
            GOTO CheckPSN
        :CheckPSN
            if %CurrentEntry% EQU %PSNEntry% GOTO SetupEarly
            GOTO CheckEarly
    ::Setups
        :SetupFull
            set CurrentEntry=%FullEntry%
            set INIentry=%Fullini%
            GOTO ObtainVariables
        :SetupMstar
            set CurrentEntry=%MstarEntry%
            set INIentry=%MSTARini%
            GOTO ObtainVariables
        :SetupPSN
            set CurrentEntry=%PSNEntry%
            set INIentry=%PSNini%
            GOTO ObtainVariables
        :SetupEarly
            set CurrentEntry=%EarlyEntry%
            set INIentry=%Earlyini%
            GOTO ObtainVariables
    :DoINIstuff
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Set _PathtoFile=%INIfile%
        Set _OldLine=%INIentry%=
        Set _NewLine=%INIentry%=%ThisFile%
        Call :_Parse "%_PathtoFile%"
        Set _Len=0
        Set _Str=%_OldLine%
        Set _Str=%_Str:"=.%987654321
        :_Loop
        If NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" Set _Str=%_Str:~9%& Set /A _Len+=9& Goto _Loop
        Set _Num=%_Str:~9,1%
        Set /A _Len=_Len+_Num
        PushD %_FilePath%
        If Exist %_FileName%.new Del %_FileName%.new
        If Exist %_FileName%.old Del %_FileName%.old
        Set _LineNo=0
        For /F "Tokens=* Eol=" %%I In (%_FileName%%_FileExt%) Do (
        Set _tmp=%%I
        Set /A _LineNo+=1
        If /I "!_tmp:~0,%_Len%!"=="%_OldLine%" (
        >>%_FileName%.new Echo %_NewLine%
        ) Else (
        If !_LineNo! GTR 1 If "!_tmp:~0,1!"=="[" Echo.>>%_FileName%.new
        SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        >>%_FileName%.new Echo %%I
        EndLocal
        ))
        Ren %_FileName%%_FileExt% %_FileName%.old
        Ren %_FileName%.new %_FileName%.ini
        PopD
        Goto :CheckEarly
        :_Parse
        Set _FilePath=%~dp1
        Set _FileName=%~n1
        Set _FileExt=%~x1
        Goto :EOF
```

I hope I haven't omitted too much to figure this out. Basically, I can see that the revision number and the day are acting like they should, but the month just reverts to "-1" instead of actually performing the subtraction, and I'm basically pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is quite simple. A number string with a leading `0` is interpreted as octal number by C function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) used by `cmd.exe` to convert a number string to an integer.

`08` and `09` are invalid numbers in [octal numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) and for that reason function `strtol` returns `0` which is subtracted next by `1` resulting in `-1`.

The simple solution is using `set /a "mm=1%mm%-101"` instead of `set /a "mm=mm-1"`. Then first the month value is concatenated as string with the character `1` building the strings `101` to `112` and so the number string has no leading `0` anymore and from this number `101` is subtracted to get `0` to `11` assigned as string to environment variable `mm`.

By the way: Use the following two command lines to get back the leading zero after subtraction:

```
set "mm=0%mm%"
set "mm=%mm:~-2%"
```

The first line concatenates `0`-`11` to `00`-`011` and the second line takes just the last two characters of this string resulting in `00`-`11` assigned finally to environment variable `mm`.

The next two lines should be replaced by: `if %mm% == 00 set "mm=12" & set /a "yy-=1"`

Comment: I think that's a very good place to start, thank you. I didn't think about 0X vs X as an algorythmic issue. I have it formatted as 0X because of the filename convention of the file(s) being downloaded, but I can certainly just do a little more work change the number format back and forth as needed. I'll give this a go and post my results, thank you so much :-)

Comment: It looks like it's working so I did this:


        `set mm=1%mm%`
        `set /a "mm=mm-101"`


At the beginning, then I have that long list of making the format back into 0X

And when we get to the 27th of a day, it's doing this:


        `if %dd%==27 (`
        `set mm=1%mm%`
        `set /a "mm=mm-101"`
        `)`<br/>


Overall, just 2 extra lines of code, and I can stop pulling my hair out. Thank you again!